# resolving this parse syntax error so that i generate my query

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to run this query below but im getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\daily.php on line 79
```

the code online 79 is this

```
   $result = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%m-%d") AS 'month and day',balance as amount FROM `aggrement`";
```

when i run this query on my `phpmyadmin` its running successfully but when i put it on my php page im getting this error above i tied to remove the double quotes(i.e these "") and replace it with the single quotes(i.e these `` `) ,im getting this notice ``
Unknown column '%m-%d' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this-

```
 $result = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%m-%d') AS 'month and day',balance as amount FROM `aggrement`";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes, for example:

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, \"%m-%d\") AS ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes. (`'`)
Or, if you want double quotes, don't forget to escape them when your PHP string is delimited by double quotes.

With double quotes:

```
 $result = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, \"%m-%d\") AS 'month and day',balance as amount FROM `aggrement`";
```

Backticks don't work as they quote field names, not strings.

Comment: thanks but it seems im getting a Notice: Undefined index: start_Date in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\daily.php on line 97

Comment: echo '<td>' . $row['start_Date'] . '</td>';

Comment: echo '<td>' . $row['start_Date'] . '</td>'; is the code on line 97

Comment: You have to use `$row["month and day"]`